# Composer throws error when installing setup.py with BeamRunPythonPipelineOperator

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-composer

I am having trouble when passing the argument "setup_file" to my BeamRunPythonPipelineOperator. Here is the traceback in Composer logs.

```
[2022-11-16, 05:03:19 UTC] {beam.py:127} WARNING - error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'csv_converter-0.0.1/csv_converter.egg-info/PKG-INFO'
[2022-11-16, 05:03:20 UTC] {beam.py:127} WARNING - Traceback (most recent call last):
[2022-11-16, 05:03:20 UTC] {beam.py:127} WARNING -   File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/utils/processes.py", line 89, in check_output
[2022-11-16, 05:03:20 UTC] {beam.py:127} WARNING -     out = subprocess.check_output(*args, **kwargs)
[2022-11-16, 05:03:20 UTC] {beam.py:127} WARNING -   File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 415, in check_output
[2022-11-16, 05:03:20 UTC] {beam.py:127} WARNING -     return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
[2022-11-16, 05:03:20 UTC] {beam.py:127} WARNING -   File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 516, in run
[2022-11-16, 05:03:20 UTC] {beam.py:127} WARNING -     raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
[2022-11-16, 05:03:20 UTC] {beam.py:127} WARNING - subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/bin/python3', 'setup.py', 'sdist', '--dist-dir', '/tmp/tmpifl6ty8k']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

I have no clue why this [Errno 2] No such file or directory. Some DAGs run just fine, while some report this error. Sometimes I get different errors such as another file from setup.py can't be found or [Errno 5] Input/Output Error

This is my operator:

```
BeamRunPythonPipelineOperator(
    task_id='xxxx',
    runner="DataflowRunner",
    py_file=f'/home/airflow/gcs/data/csv_converter/main.py',
    pipeline_options={
        'project_id': project_id,
        'input_path': input_path,
        'output_path': output_path,
        'schema_path': schema_path,
        'service_account': service_account,     
        'no_use_public_ips': True,
        'subnetwork': subnetwork,      
        'staging_location': staging_location,
        'temp_location': temp_location,
        "setup_file": f'/home/airflow/gcs/data/csv_converter/setup.py',
        "machine_type": "n1-standard-4",
        "num_workers": 5,
        "max_num_workers": 10,
    },
    py_options=[],
    py_interpreter='python3',
    py_system_site_packages=False,
    dataflow_config=DataflowConfiguration(
        job_name='{{task.task_id}}',
        location=gce_region,
        wait_until_finished=False,
        gcp_conn_id="dataflow_conn"
    ),
)
```

This error is very frustrating as I have no clue how to fix it and haven't found anyone experiencing the same issue.

Some context: Our process consists of triggering DAGs when .CSVs land in a bucket. At first I thought it was a problem with the schedulers and concurrency since we had some zombie tasks. I noticed that with 2 schedulers with 2 vCPUs, we notice a CPU usage around ~80% (always stuck at >3/4 vCPUs, even though DAGs are triggered in a burst fashion when multiple .CSVs land). I tried increasing the schedulers to 4 and 4 vCPUs but the problem persists. I expect the process to install my package correctly.

- Composer version: 2.0.31
- Airflow version: 2.3.3
- apache-airflow-providers-google version: 8.1.0
- apache-beam version: 2.41.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this issue previously, I think if you use the `setup.py` in the root from the `Composer` `DAG` folder, it will solve your issue.

I also recommend you to deploy your `Beam` job folder to `dags` instead of `data`.

`data` is more used for `Airflow` variables.

Example :

```py
# Get DAG folder via an env var
dag_folder = os.getenv("DAGS_FOLDER")

BeamRunPythonPipelineOperator(
    task_id='xxxx',
    runner="DataflowRunner",
    py_file=f'/home/airflow/gcs/dags/csv_converter/main.py',
    pipeline_options={
        'project_id': project_id,
        'input_path': input_path,
        'output_path': output_path,
        'schema_path': schema_path,
        'service_account': service_account,     
        'no_use_public_ips': True,
        'subnetwork': subnetwork,      
        'staging_location': staging_location,
        'temp_location': temp_location,
        'setup_file': f"{dag_folder}/setup.py",
        "machine_type": "n1-standard-4",
        "num_workers": 5,
        "max_num_workers": 10,
    },
    py_options=[],
    py_interpreter='python3',
    py_system_site_packages=False,
    dataflow_config=DataflowConfiguration(
        job_name='{{task.task_id}}',
        location=gce_region,
        wait_until_finished=False,
        gcp_conn_id="dataflow_conn"
    ),
)
```

Some explanations :

- The `setup.py` is used at the root of `DAG` folder : `{composer_bucket}/dags/setup.py`
- The `dag_folder` is retrieve from a `Composer` env var
- The setup is set as option in the `Beam` operator with the following way :         `'setup_file': f"{dag_folder}/setup.py"`

Comment: Can you move your `main.py` in `{composer_bucket}/dags` instead of `{composer_bucket}/data` please ?

Comment: Hello Mazlum. Thank you for answering so quickly. I left my main.py in {composer_bucket}/data/main.py and moved my setup.py to the dags folder. I get a ModuleNotFound. 

in main.py I'm trying to relatively import the file that contains the pipeline code.
`from pipeline import csv_to_avro`
Here is where the DAG crashes. It used to work before.
Edit: I just saw your comment. Moving my Dataflow code to dags/

Comment: You're welcome, I edited my answer to recommend you to move your main.py and job folder to `dags` folder instead of `data`.

Comment: Moving my Dataflow code to the dags folder actually worked! I am also not getting these weird errors (error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'csv_converter-0.0.1/csv_converter.egg-info/PKG-INFO') anymore. Not sure how you figured it out or what causes it but thanks!!

Comment: You’re very welcome :), can you upvote my answer in order make it more visible and help others ?

Comment: I would gladly do it but I do not have 15 reputation